# ¿Como ejecutar .php en python?

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

Buen día, tengo el siguiente script en `python` que se llama `test.py`:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["php", "load_data.php"])
```

la idea es ejecutar otro script `php` en el cual hago un `LOAD DATA INFILE` a una tabla de `MySQL`, pero me genera el siguiente error:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
    File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.call<["php","load_data.php"]>
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 537, in call
   with Popen<*popenargs, **kwargs> as p:
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py" line 859, in __init__
   restore_signals, start_new_session>
File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1114, in _execute_child startupinfo>
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Si ejecuto el script `load_data.php` directo en un navegador web, funciona sin ningún problema por lo cual me parece que el problema esta en `python`, cabe mencionar que esto ya lo he hecho correctamente antes pero con `python 3.6`, alguna idea si me hace falta configurar algo o agregar alguna librería.

Tengo `php5.3`, `apache 2.2.21`, `mysql5.5.20`, `python3.4`

Saludos!

Comment: El error dice que no encuentra el archivo que estas especificando. Prueba poniendo la rura absoluta del script php a ver que pasa.

Comment: Ya le puse la ruta absoluta y me muestra exactamente el mismo error :/

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, creé una carpeta con los programas a correr.

```
workspace/
    |-- main.py
    |-- main.php
```

El contenido de main.py es:

```
import subprocess

def main():
    subprocess.call(["php", "main.php"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Y el de main.php es:

```
<?php
echo "Dentro de archivo php";
?>
```

Funcionó correctamente.

Traté de reproducir el error de dos maneras diferentes.
La primera fue errando el nombre del archivo main.php y obtuve el error:

> Could not open input file:

La segunda fue errando el nombre del programa que lo abre, i.e, "php" y obtuve el error que describes.

Entonces, como lo entiendo, quizás tienes que revisar que puedes correr tu script de php desde la terminal con un simple:

```
$php tu_script.php
```

Si no puedes correrlo, pero estás seguro que tienes instalado php, puedes configurar las variables de entorno para añadir tu script de php a una variable (para Windows) o agregar la ruta a tu path o hacer un enlace simbólico de donde se encuentre tu archivo "php" a /usr/local/bin/php (para distribuciones de Linux) y luego asegurarte de que puedas correr tu script desde tu consola.

Si estás en windows recuerda que cada que edites una variable de entorno (la de PATH, en este caso) y des aceptar, etc, etc., para no abrir y cerrar terminales corre el comando `refreshenv` y se recargan las variables de entorno.

Esto que te comento lo probé con éxito dentro de Windows 10 tanto con python 2.7.13 como con python 3.4.0 y python 3.6.1